# Interpolator for ViewFlipper

Tags: android, animation, interpolation, viewflipper

What interpolator should I use for a viewflipper that contains some images to see the images continuous, I mean to see the end of the image that goes to left and the the begin of the image that come from right? (sorry for my description, I hope you understand what I mean to say). I use animation (to left and to right) for viewflipper but the images come appear alone and it is not continuous.

Have anyone any idea what should be the solution?

Comment: Have you tried a linear interpolator?

Comment: yes, I tried it but it does not exact like this, it is some like what I want but not exact.

Comment: And you have set flipInterval to 0?

Comment: no, I set flipinterval to 2000 because I have this time for displaying each image. it 's not ok? if flipinterval is 0 then each images appear for one moment.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted the images to be in motion constantly. So it should be ok.

I just now tried creating a ViewFlipper with a linear interpolator, setting the in- and out-Animations as well as having a flipInterval of 2000, and I think it worked in the way you want it. Are you sure your in and out animations are correct?

Comment: I get in and out animation from anim folder from developer : push_left_in, push_left_out, push_right_in, push_right_out

Comment: What in and out animation you used?

Comment: When I try those animations the result is much different. I will post an example as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

Setting up your ViewFlipper:

```
    ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    flipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in);
    flipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out);
    flipper.startFlipping();
```

from layout XML:

```
<ViewFlipper 
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:flipInterval="2000">
    <ImageView...
    .../>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Animations:
in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="150"/>
```

out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%" android:duration="150"/>
```